UV dependency of hair nodes
Are hair or fur grooms created using hair nodes dependent on UVs or can they be made on a mesh that doesn't have UVs?

You can answer this question very simply yourself: take an object like the default cube, delete the UV map under Data > UV Maps and then try to add fur. In the bottom status bar you will get an error message "Mesh UV map required" (and no fur will appear on the cube).
